# Try to import code from github to glitch but error message has shown

Tags: github, glitch-framework

I am trying to import code from GitHub to Glitch in order to host the website for free online so that I can collaborate with others. But like shown, there's an error message every time.
[image: screenshot]
I have made the [grepository](https://github.com/liuxiaotong1/templatemo_545_finance_business) public.
Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Reproducible example (or MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: What does the error message say? How many files are there in the repo? If you don't push your commits nothing will be on github

Answer (score 0):

Aha...you need to type `https://github.com/liuxiaotong1/templatemo_545_finance_buisness`. You added `.git` at the end - that's not necessary.

Also you know GitHub also has free static web hosting? Open your repo settings and find **GitHub Pages**.